# How can I combine multiple .change triggers together?

Tags: jquery

I have the following functions:

```
$("input[id^='Position_']").change(function () { update('Position'); })
$("input[id^='Status_']").change(function () { update('Status'); })
$("input[id^='Location_']").change(function () { update('Location'); })
```

Is there some way that I could combine these functions into one and have the parameter passed in the update function be set automatically based on whichever field value changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("input[id^='Position_'], input[id^='Status_'], input[id^='Position_']").change(function(e) {
    var type = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[0];
    update(type);
});
```

Comment: Is there a way I could limit this to just the input types starting with "Position_" "Status_" or "Location_" ?

Comment: Sure, I'll edit my answer to include your types you used above.

Comment: Quick question. What do you mean by function(e) ? Why "e" ?

Comment: Oh, the function receives one parameter, the Event object. `e` is just the shorthand I usually use. You don't use the event, so you wouldn't have to include it-- it's just habit for me. You would use it for things like `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the default action from occurring (e.g., if you bound a click handler to a link and didn't want the browser to actually follow the link).